# Is there a way to “reject” a `XCTestExpectation`?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tdd, xctest

I would like to make sure that in one particular case a certain `NSNotification` is not sent. Is there an easy way to achieve this with `XCTestCase`?

Comment: Have you looked at mocks?

Comment: @CrimsonChris, yes I use OCMock. Do you suggest mocking `NSNotificationCenter` and `reject` its `postNotification` method?

Comment: It would probably be cleaner to mock the method in your class that does the actual posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a helper method to subscribe to the NSNotification.  Upon receiving it, set a BOOL.  Test against that BOOL's value (lack of being changed).

Answer (score 0):

You can invert an expectation to verify is not fullfilled:

```
XCTestExpectation *exp = [self expectationWithDescription:@"exp"];
exp.inverted = YES;
```

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestexpectation/2806573-inverted?language=objc)